# Как проверить число на дробность в языке программирования

Tags: c#

для решения одной задачи мне нужно проверить вьіходящее число на дробность, но я незнаю как ето сделать . Помогите пожайлуста

Comment: Слишком абстрактный вопрос. Например проверить что число не равно своему округлению

Comment: Например, проверить, что `x == Math.Round(x)`

Comment: а что есть "дробность" ?

Answer (score 0):

Например на выходе число `a = 2.1`
Проверка

```
if (a is double) 
    Console.WriteLine("Число дробное");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Число не дробное");
```

Или сравни с его округлённым значением

```
if(x == Math.Round(x))
   Console.Write("Число не дробное");
```

Comment: Через `is` вы проверите только тип переменной. Обычно тип переменной в строго типизированном языке и так известен заранее.